# can't make cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am new to javascript. I tried to make a cookie that displays cookie if site is visited before, otherwise asks name. I don't know why the script doesn't work. Please help me debug.
    `

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> //-----------
> function check()
> {
> if(document.cookie.length>0){
> return document.cookie
> }
> else
> return ""
> }
> //---------
> function get(){
> var today=new date()
> today.setDate(today+1)
> var name=check()
> if(name=="")
> {name=prompt("name?","")
> document.cookie="username="+name+";expires="+today.toUTCString()
> }
> else
> document.write("welcome back"+document.cookie)
> }
> </script>
> </head>
> <body >
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> get();
> </script>
> </body> 
> </html>`<html> 
> this is so frustrating! Passerby already edited the body of this post; your edit must be more substantive to override the current edit.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today=new Date();
```

With Capital D.

**Update:**
Run this code on a [localhost](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: thanks @grmmph. At least i got the prompt. But I don't get the cookie displayed after i close and reopen the file. Please help on this one.

Comment: That's strange. Testing your code works only when I run it on a localhost. Try to run your page through a localhost. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html